# saving data from multiple activites to one id firebase database instead of creating two different ids

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

//1..i want to send pic from one activity and data from another activity into same database firebase having 1 same id instead of creating 2 different ids(one for pic and another for data(name,notice etc as mentioned below))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIx56.png) here is an idea ..for storing different activities data into same id firebase..this isnot my example but i have same problem...but i dont want two ids ,i want one id for pic Uri and data as well.

//2..Here is my 1st activity..In this activity i have camera to capture image then send this Pic Uri to upload class(gettersetter class) for storing into database firebase. here i have sent pic Uri to gettersetter class.

**popQuickActivity.java**

```
if(imgUri!=null){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading.....");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference fileReference=mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"." +getFileExtension(imgUri));
        fileReference.putFile(imgUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Handler handler=new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                },500);
                Toast.makeText(popQuickActivity.this, "Uploaded successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();

                upload  upload=new upload(downloadUrl);

                String uploadId=mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);

            }
```

// here is my upload(gettersetter class)...img uri is here

**upload.java**

public class upload {

```
private String mImageUri;
private String mNoticeNo;
private String mName;
private String mDate;
private String mCharge;
private String mDescription;
private String mCnic;

public upload(){

}


public upload(String name, String noticeNo, String date, String amountCharge, String des, String cnic, String description) {

    if(description.trim().equals("")){

        description="No Description";
    }

    mName=name;
    mCharge=amountCharge;
    mDate=date;
    mCnic=cnic;
    mNoticeNo=noticeNo;
    mDescription=description;


}

public upload(String downloadUrl) {
    mImageUri=downloadUrl;
}

public String getmImageUri() {
    return mImageUri;
}

public void setmImageUri(String mImageUri) {
    this.mImageUri = mImageUri;
}

public String getmNoticeNo() {
    return mNoticeNo;
}

public void setmNoticeNo(String mNoticeNo) {
    this.mNoticeNo = mNoticeNo;
}

public String getmName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setmName(String mName) {
    this.mName = mName;
}

public String getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setmDate(String mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

public String getmCharge() {
    return mCharge;
}

public void setmCharge(String mCharge) {
    this.mCharge = mCharge;
}

public String getmDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}

public void setmDescription(String mDescription) {
    this.mDescription = mDescription;
}

public String getmCnic() {
    return mCnic;
}

public void setmCnic(String mCnic) {
    this.mCnic = mCnic;
}
```

}

//here is my another activity..here i am sending data(name,noticeNo,date etc) to gettersetter class(upload class) same place in firebase...but it is creating two different id instead of creating one id and storing both img and data in one same id.

**QuickChallan.java**

public void doIt(View view) {

```
    String Name=name.getText().toString().trim();
    String NoticeNo=noticeno.getText().toString().trim();
    String Cnic=cnic.getText().toString().trim();
    String AmountCharge=amountcharge.getText().toString().trim();
    String Date=date.getText().toString().trim();
    String Des=des.getText().toString().trim();



   upload upload=new upload(Name,NoticeNo,Date,AmountCharge,Des,Cnic,Des);

    String uploadId=mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
    mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates two random ID, because in the activity `popQuickActivity.java` you are creating an ID and storing it in the variable `uploadId`.

Then in the activity `QuickChallan.java` you also create another ID and store it in the variable `uploadId` but this time u add different data.

To only use one ID. In the first activity (`popQuickActivity.java`) after storing the image url under the id, you need to add it inside an `intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity2.this, activity1.class);
intent.putExtra("id", uploadId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the second activity :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String id = bundle.getString("id");
mDatabaseRef.child(id).setValue(upload);
```

This way in the second activity you don't create another ID using the `push()`, therefore you ofcourse you have to remove `uploadId=mDatabaseRef.push().getKey()` since this line is creating another ID.

Comment: QuickChallan
-LuYg9GC9qbzjtsf2ouA
mCharge: 
""
mCnic: 
""
mDate: 
""
mDescription: 
"No Description"
mName: 
""
mNoticeNo: 
""              .....still not working..broo

Comment: In the second activity use the following :`Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("posts", Name);
    childUpdates.put("Notice No", noticeNo);

    mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).updateChildren(childUpdates);` instead of setValue

Comment: its working bro...thank uu bro..i had struck in this problem more than 2 weeks..u saved my time..thank u